# Subtracting COUNT results in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

In my SQLite query, I create two temp tables, both of which have a column with `COUNT` results. I then combine these two columns into a new table.

This part of the query works fine: I get the two columns of numbers in my new table.

I named these two columns using `as C1` and `as C2`. But when I add a third calculated column containing the expression `C1-C2`, this third column contains only zeros.

> How can I subtract the numbers using my column names?

Answer (score 0):

How about?

SELECT c1, c2, (c1 - c2) as `difference`  FROM table